# Magento 1.9.2.4 installation stuck in Localization

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, cpanel

I'm installing Magento 1.9.2.4 on cPanel . During installation I'm facing problem magento stuck in **"Localization"** as image below:

[image]

Kindly help to sort this as soon please.

Answer (score 0):

Its is mostly caused by some PHP error in the code. First enable the PHP error reporting by add below code in `index.php` after `<?php` tag under your magento installation directory.

```
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(-1);
```

> After you will get the information about the problem and you will solve this problem, you should disable php error reporting again, so no error will be displayed for the public (because of security reasons).

After enabled the PHP error reporting, refresh the page again. It will show the error to you. In my case, I also getting same problem because I didn't install  php DOM module.